# Resolving a large amount of IP addresses with PHP

Tags: php, pcntl, gethostbyaddr

I need to resolve a large amount of IP addresses.  I'm using [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr) for it.

I just recently read about using [`pcntl_fork()`](http://php.net/pcntl_fork) and that if you do fork, you don't have to wait for a timeout.

Since `gethostbyaddr` will take a long time (30 seconds, I think) to resolve a host before timeout, is `pcntl_fork` practical for use with a large amount of IP addresses?

Comment: If this is a core component of your service, which seems like it, if you need to make a lot of those queries, I'd say a much more elaborate setup is in order here. You'll probably want a very reliable and hand-tweaked DNS server close by, which caches and queries for you. On the PHP side, a queue/worker system with hand-tuned workers seems appropriate. Just a simple `gethostbyaddr` is easy, but probably not the tool to use if this is a core functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a high-performance, asynchronous DNS library for PHP. Fortunately, [Net_DNS2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2) is exactly that.